# Make field editable in comment form

Tags: forms

Could you please help me with the following task? I need to make the existing field (name Clarify, type select - "clarification required/clarification isn't required") to be editable from display view (not on the Edit tab) and I need to place this field next to Comment field (see the screenshot).

I'm trying to use hook_alter_form in the following way, but with no luck. I know the below code is wrong and I need a little help to know which way to go.

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_node_support_ticket_form') {
    $form['field_clarify'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Clarify',
    );

    $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_support_comment_submit';
  }
}

function custom_support_comment_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $node_wrapper->field_clarify->set($form_state['values']['field_clarify']);
  $node_wrapper->save();  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need `'options' => array('clarification required', 'clarification isn\'t required')` for select because you need options. Then you need to make sure your module name is `custom` (unless you don't want to expose your module name). Also, you pass your function name to `$form['#validate'][]` but it ends with _submit (it should be _validate).

There are what I found at the first glance. I didn't check the code.

Comment: Something like this?

function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'comment_node_support_ticket_form') {
$form['field_clarify'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Clarify',
  '#options' => array('clarification required', 'clarification isn\'t required'
);
$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_support_comment_submit';
}
}

Comment: function custom_support_comment_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$node_wrapper->field_clarify->set($form_state['values']['field_clarify']);
$node_wrapper->save();
}

Comment: Yeah, you did it right :)